# How to write a file path in Json for this REST_API on Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: json, rest, azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory V2 and I wonder whether anyone could help me writing the file path for this REST_API Activity that has a Body parameter that can only be written in JSON.

This REST_API is part of a pipeline that must be triggered by an event. As you can see below the Pipeline parameter "BlobName" requires a file path to be set dynamically. This is a blob file that has to be stored in this container called "source-csv". I am trying to use `source-csv\@{triggerBody().filename}` on the "Trigger Run Parameters" but it won't work. Can anyone help please?

[image: Pipeline parameters on the bottom as mention above and trigger run parameters on the right hand side]

Answer (score 0):

The below is the solution:

{"blobname": "source-csv/@{triggerBody().filename}"}

Thanks